# can't ssh after assigning an elastic ip

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I configured my instance. Its up and running. I can ssh in with my key (provisioned by chef/knife) before assigning an elastic IP.  For example this works (before EIP):

`ssh -F .ssh/config ec2-ww-xx-yy-zz.us-west1.computer.amazonaws.com`

After assigning an EIP I get a:

`Permission denied (publickey)`

error message as its checking my home folder for the key instead of the project directory.

I even specified the config directory an the EIP:

`ssh -F .ssh/config ubuntu@ww.xx.yy.zz -v`

which returns a "Connection timed out message".

When I use Elastic Fox I can see the EIP was associated correctly. Am I missing an AWS setting which denies SSH to EIPs?

Comment: On a side note I made sure port 22 was wide open in the aws security group

Comment: Seems to be working now. Added a wait function to my bash script and it finally picked it up.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Once an EC2 instance is launched, it will assign a public and private IP address.  An instance's private IP address will never change during the lifetime of that instance.  *However, its public dns address can change under certain circumstances.*

So, after you associate an EIP to any instance, use that IP to login into your machine.

Comment: The system already connected to elastic IP and when we ssh in to the node, it tries to connect to the old IP as we have added finger print when the domain name is originally resolved.

Comment: @sarat - you should update the finger-print, I would remove the finger that is associated with that domain/node and try to ssh again, which will add a new finger-print to the ssh.

Answer (score 0):

When you associate an Elastic IP Address to your instance, it will assign a new Public DNS address to it. One thing to note is your known hosts to are stored in the `/Users/stuart/.ssh/known_hosts` file and once you assign the elastic IP address and try to ssh back into the instance, it just can not work since the Public domain name is change. You need to replace this with the new one.
To do that use the command:

```
ssh-keygen -R ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xx.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

remember that that is the new Public DNS name assigned to the server after associating an IP address.
Cheers!