# Can't get Amazon EC2 instance work

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am trying to setup an amazon ec2 instance for first time.

I've created one with ubuntu 10.4, managed to connect to ssh and installed mongodb, mysql, php and apache which need for my proyect(also python but it is already setup).

Then I associated an elastic ip to the instance, but when I try to open the IP, I can't. It gives timeout.

Could it be that the apache root is not where I think it is?(/var/www/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [can't ssh after assigning an elastic ip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298213/cant-ssh-after-assigning-an-elastic-ip)

Comment: possible non reader: I said that ssh is working fine...

Comment: "...Then I associated an elastic ip to the instance, but when I try to get in, I cant...". If that is not what you meant you should edit your post to clarify.

Comment: I changed, maybe it was not expressed correctly. What I mean is that I  cant access the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the security group that is associated with the instance.  Make sure that you open up port 80.

Also make sure that apache is started, and configured to start on boot.

If you're logged in, you should be able to use wget localhost to verify if apache is serving up pages.

Comment: Yeah, was that. Thanks